# Some problem un-static local variable with static fuction in C?

Tags: c, linux

My process is terminated with segmentation fault rarely.

Segmentaion fault point is at line 15 (while (isspace (*b))).

When I analyze coredump, argument funcname is shorter than buff and has valid address.

How is it possible? What should I do?

```
static char *
strip_funcname (char *name, const char *funcname)
{ 
    char buff[80];
    char *e, *b = buff;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (name == NULL || funcname == NULL)
        return NULL;

    strncpy (buff, funcname, sizeof (buff));
    buff[sizeof (buff) - 1] = '\0';

    /* Skip beginning space. */
    while (isspace (*b))  <===== Segmentation fault point
        ++b;

    if (*b == '(')
    { 
        /* funcname == "(Word)". */
        e = buff + strlen (buff) - 1;

        while (*b == ' ' || *b == '(')
            ++b;

        while (*e == ' ' || *e == ')')
            --e;
        e++;

        *e = '\0';
    }
    else
    { 
        /* funcname == "Word ()". */

        e = strchr (b, '(');
        if (e) 
            *e-- = '\0';
        else
            e = buff + strlen (buff) - 1;

        while (isspace (*e))
            *e-- = '\0';
    }

    strcpy (name, b);

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. It should include a simple `main` function that calls your `strip_funcname` function.

Comment: You have a few loops where you increase `b`, but you never check for the string null-terminator. You also have some loops around `e` but you never check for it possibly passing the beginning of `buff` (or `b`).

Comment: Does the string contain characters beyond what's representable as an `unsigned char`? Thanks to a C language design mistakes in the ctype.h library, isspace will crash & burn when that happens. A possible work-around for these language flaws is to cast the argument to `unsigned char` before passing it to ctype.h functions. Similarly, the presence of `strncpy` in the C standard library is another language design mistake and that function should be avoided whenever dealing with C strings. The benefit of using C is that all language design problems are well-known by now (and will not get fixed).